# IE 8 is not showing some images

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I have this [page](http://ferrajes.karinapp.com/?md=product), and on IE 9 the images are loading very well but on previous versions aren't on FF, Chrome, Opera, Safari all the things are well is just on those versions of IE and with specific images. I've checked the Dev Tools of iE8 and everything is fine.

Thanks!

Comment: Some of the images are `.bmp` files.  That's probably your issue, I didn't think browsers supported that image type.

Comment: Start by getting rid of the `<?xml version="1.0" ?>` that starts your page. Also, correct the errors http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fferrajes.karinapp.com%2F%3Fmd%3Dproduct&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: @j08691, thanks for the advice i'm gonna fix that after, fix the problem of the images, Rocket, some of the files that are not loading are .jpg.